# What is the best way to call repaint() at regular intervals in my Java2D program?

Tags: java, java-2d

I'm looking to call repaint() in my Java2D simulator at regular intervals.

What would be the best way to do this?  Should I start another thread and have a loop that keeps track of currentTimeMillis()?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Does your simulator need to 'simulate as fast as possible' or 'simulate at a fixed rate'? The answer may change how you structure this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use timer function in java ([javax.swing.Timer](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/other/10time/20timer.html))

and this may useful for you [efiicient way to repaint](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t113451.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a Timer. If its a Swing application use a Swing Timer. If its AWT then use TimerTask.

Comment: Swing's `Timer` works fine for AWT. With `java.util.Timer` you would need to do the `invokeLater` yourself.